# Laravel - Is it possible to pass the general route name as a route group?

Tags: laravel

I have the following api route:

```
GET /api/v1/users
POST /api/v1/users // middleware auth
```

In my `api.php` I have the following code for this:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
    require __DIR__ . '/v1/api/users.php';
});
```

In my `v1/api/users.php` I have this code:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/users', function (Request $request) {
        return [];
    })->name('create');
});

Route::get('/users', function (Request $request) {
    return [];
})->name('index');
```

My goal is to give the name a prefix `users.`. So that I can then the route name: `users.delete` or `users.index` as the name. **Here my attempt:** For this reason I tried to wrap the above code into a Route::group:

```php
Route::group(['name' => 'users.'], function() {

    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {

        Route::post('/users', function (Request $request) {
            return $request->user();
        })->name('delete');

        Route::get('/users', function (Request $request) {
            return [];
        })->name('index');

});
```

**Problem** However, Laravel then no longer recognises the wrapped routes. How can I rewrite this so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Route name prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-name-prefixes) are configured as follows:

```
Route::name('users.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/users', function () {
        // Route assigned name "users.index"...
    })->name('index');
});
```

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thank you and have a nice day! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Base on your Routes you can chain the `name()` after the `middleware()` :

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->name('users.')->group(function () {

    Route::post('/users', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    })->name('delete');

    Route::get('/users', function (Request $request) {
        return [];
    })->name('index');
});
```

You can also use only the `group()` :

```
Route::group(['name' => 'users.', 'middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function() {
    Route::post('/users', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    })->name('delete');

    Route::get('/users', function (Request $request) {
        return [];
    })->name('index');
});
```